# Regenerative Braking

Tags: motor, dc, series

It is often said that regenerative braking is difficult to implement on a DC series wound Traction motor with brushes .Many EV owners that do there own conversions use a series motor like a "warp 11" with an off the shelf controller with no regen braking  .                              I haven't done regen on series      because nobody has asked me   to .I would like to see what others would do ?  Is there a simple way ?There is an urban myth about putting the motor into reverse while driving ..this worries me is it true?

Comment: Who says it (often)? Hyperlink?

Comment: Engineering by heresay is not a good technique.

Comment: Its been said by university acedemics and in many old textbooks of the pre Internet era.

Comment: @OlinLathrop -- indeed; some would say it's heresy!

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the main difficulty is that the armature current reverses during regenerative braking. In order to maintain the proper direction of field current, you would need to reverse the field connection when braking is initiated. Rather that do that, I think that it would be better to simply disconnect the field and connect it to a separate power supply. Regenerative braking can only be provided with an electronic speed control and a regenerative controller would normally be designed to include a separate field supply.

Comment: Using a separate field supply will work and it has been done before .What is called for is a lowvoltage high current supply.Not insurmountable these days .BUT if the series connection were maintained possibly through some switching then the high current is there when its needed .This could give a cheaper lighter system .